# Call function from another function error C++

Tags: c++, function, class

I'm trying to get my player1Hand function to work with my deck function so cards can be drawn from the deck and used in each player function. I'm not sure how to call one function from another function because it's saying,
    `main.cpp:68:10: error: 'deck' was not declared in this scope`

```
cout << deck[ z ].rank << " of " << deck[ z ].suit << endl;
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //for rand and srand
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <ctime> // time function for seed value
#include "Card.h"

using namespace std;



#define pause cout << endl; system("pause")

class CardClass {
public: 

  struct card

  {
    string rank;//this example uses C++ string notation
    string suit;
    int value;
  };
public:
  void deckFunction ();

private:

};

void CardClass::deckFunction () {
  srand(time(0));

  struct card deck[52];  // An array of cards named deck, size 52


  const string ranks[ ] = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
    "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

  const string suits[ ] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };

  int k = 0; 

  for ( int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      deck[ k ].rank = ranks[ i ];
      deck[ k ].suit = suits[ j ];
      k++;
    }
  }

}

void Players::player1hand () {

  CardClass deckFunc;
  deckFunc.deckFunction();
  int p1Chips = 10;
  int pot = 0;
  int player1bet = 0;
  srand(time(0));
  char ans;
  do {
    int z = rand () % 52;

    cout << deck[ z ].rank << " of " << deck[ z ].suit << endl;
    cout << "Place bet: ";
    cin >> player1bet;
    if (player1bet > 0) {
      pot = pot + player1bet;
      p1Chips = p1Chips - player1bet;
      cout << pot << endl;
      cout << p1Chips << endl;

    }
    else {
      cout << "Player 1 folds.";
      cin >> ans;
    }
    cout << "Would you like another card? " << endl;
    cin >> ans;
  } while (ans == 'y');

}



int main()
{
  Players player1;
  player1.player1hand();

  pause;

  return 0;

}
```

Card.h file (not really used yet):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Players
{
public:
void player1hand ();
void player2hand ();
void player3hand ();
void player4hand ();
void player5hand ();
void player6hand ();
private:


};
```

I know some of the functions and class interaction is a bit sloppy right now but I'm just trying to get everything to work. So basically, I need the player class to take a card from the deck class, then allow them to place a bet, then repeat this process. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full error?

Comment: Okay, just made the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
struct card deck[52];
```

This defines `deck` in function `CardClass::deckFunction`. This does not make `deck` visible in `Players::player1hand`.

You can resolve this by passing `deck` to `player1Hand` as an argument.

Change the member functions of `Players` to include an additional argument.

```
class Players
{
   public:
      void player1hand (card deck[]);
      void player2hand (card deck[]);
      void player3hand (card deck[]);
      void player4hand (card deck[]);
      void player5hand (card deck[]);
      void player6hand (card deck[]);
   private:
};
```

Then, update the implementation of the functions. The updated `Players::player1hand` would look like:

```
void Players::player1hand (card deck[]) {
   // ... include the body of the function
}
```

Comment: Passing deck like this: void Players::player1hand (deck) gives me the error, 'player1hand' declared void?

Comment: When I update my card.h file like you suggested, it says card was not declared? Can I include the card struct in this class somehow?

Comment: @austin541, Put the definition of `struct card` in a .h file. Then, `#include` the .h file wherever you need to access its members. You can use a forward declaration in you need only to use a pointer or reference to the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
struct card deck[52];
```

is visible only in `void CardClass::deckFunction ()`, and you are trying to access it outside in `void Players::player1hand()`